# Apache mod_rewrite and mod_proxy conflict

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am using Apache, mod_proxy and mod_rewrite

I wish for the following:

https://www.example.com.*?secure=true to return a 403

https://www.example.com.* to proxy to https://www.example.org

I have configuration as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} secure=true
RewriteRule .* - [F]

ProxyPass / https://www.example.org/
```

However, for both URLs, they are proxied to https://www.example.org and the first URL is not forbidden.  Using mod_rewrite logging, I can see it does match the URL and it says it will change the response to 403, but doesn't.

Is there a precedence issue, i.e. does ProxyPass override mod_rewrite?

(I understand secure=true in its self is a problem, but I have no control over the application, hence the Apache rule).

Comment: there is no conflict there, just match trailing slashes in the proxypass directive.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are suggesting?

Comment: 'ProxyPass / https://www.example.org/' with a trailing slash at the target the same as with the origin, if you don't match trailing slashes you'll get odd results.

Comment: Ahh, that was an error when changing the URL to example.org to fit in with ServerFault's restrictions, it does actually have a trailing slash. Ill edit my question if I can.